# Text shifts when adjacent text is clicked in IE8-mode

Tags: html, css

I'm stumped.  I've got a paragraph on my page that, when clicked, causes some nearby text to shift up when I browse the page with IE8.  I've stripped everything out to get a good repro.  In my repro case it's actually worse.  If I click some other text it will cause the text to shift back down.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <title>IE8 text shift</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin: 100px 0;">margin</div>
    <div style="width:32px; height:32px; float:left; background: Yellow;">float</div>
    <div>
        <!-- This HTML comes from an external system.  I cannot remove      -->
        <!-- the <div style="clear:both;"></div>, which is always included. -->
        <p>Click on this first paragraph and the "abc" text jumps up.</p>
        <p>Click on this second paragraph and the "abc" text jumps down.</p>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <!-- End External HTML -->
    </div>
    <div>abc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd happily delete the `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` except that it is out of my control.  Everything outside the area indicated by comments is in my control.

Works fine in chrome and firefox.

**Edit:** It seems I was wrong about the first paragraph needing to be long.  In fact, if it is too long, I lose my repro.  I've updated my repro to use a shorter first paragraph.

**Edit:** It has something to do with the top div's margin.  If I add more paragraphs, the shift goes away.  But if I then increase the margin on that div, the shift returns.

**Update:** I confirmed this does not repro in actual ie 8 (had to use my old XP computer).  This is an IE9 in IE8 mode issue only.  **Also,** I figured out *I am able to fix it* by adding `style="overflow: hidden;` to the parent div of the paragraphs.

Comment: It seems to be working for me, I don't see any text shift.

Comment: Do you have an eternal CSS file that's still being applied?

Comment: @Soufiane - I modified my repro.  I think the first paragraph needs to actually be short, not long.  Does shortening the paragraph make a difference for you?

Comment: @jnpcl - Nope.  The code you see is copied and pasted from my test file.

Comment: @jnpcl: lol, _eternal_ css... the _persistent_ style sheet.

Comment: @gilly3: There is absolutely nothing within the provided code that would cause a mouse click to change the text. Are you sure it's not a browser addon?

Comment: Cannot quite reproduce in IE 8 http://jsbin.com/oqome5

Comment: @Sean - Your link repros for me on two machines.  Note that I am using IE9, and it is in IE8 mode.  Maybe this is one of those rare occurances where IE8 mode differs from actual IE8.

Comment: @Everyone - Thanks for your help, I was able to resolve it (see my updated question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is specific to IE9-in-IE8-mode.  The solution is to hide the overflow of the parent div.

```
<body>
    <div style="margin: 100px 0;">margin</div>
    <div style="width:32px; height:32px; float:left; background: Yellow;">float</div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden">
        <p>Click on this first paragraph and the "abc" text no longer jumps up.</p>
        <p>Click on this second paragraph and the "abc" text no longer jumps down.</p>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>abc</div>
</body>
```